# Tex document compiles fine, but converting it to .odt or .docx failes for mk4ht and pandoc

Tags: pdftex, pandoc, msword, dvi, convert

I am able to compile my document fine using the pdflatex chain in Kile, but when I try to convert it to an .odt file using `mk4ht oolatex 0.main.tex` I get the following error.

```
! pdfTeX error (\pdfcolorstack): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0). 
\set@color ->\pdfcolorstack
```

Using `pandoc 0.main.tex --bibliography="/home/thesisprimary.bib" --bibliography="/home/thesissecondary.bib" ---csl="/home/chicago-note-bibliography.csl" -o compile_document.docx` I get

```
Error at "0.main.tex" (line 85, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting \end{document}
\end{document}
 ^
```

Previously, either of these methods worked fine. I am not sure what's going on now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{maine-thesis}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago} 
\usepackage[main=american,vietnamese]{babel} 
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,gray]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\addbibresource{thesisprimary.bib} 
\addbibresource{thesissecondary.bib}

\begin{document}

\include{1.introduction}                
\include{2.theory}
\include{3.historiography}              
\include{4.background}
\include{5.methodology}         
\include{6.analysis}
\include{7.findings}
\include{8.conclusion}
\include{appendixA}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Convert a document  is always problematic, but specially when the source is the most complex format (i.e., LaTeX). If you need regularly outputs of your in several formats, this is the wrong workflow. Consider export to the simplest source  (i.e., in markdown), wedit the document in this format only, and  then convert  it to LaTeX, LibreOffice and whatever. The opposite way will always  be a pain.

Answer (score 3):

I can compile simplified example when I remove `pdftex` option from `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{maine-thesis}  
\usepackage[]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago} 
\usepackage[main=american,vietnamese]{babel} 
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,gray]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\addbibresource{thesisprimary.bib} 
\addbibresource{thesissecondary.bib}

\begin{document}

hello world

\end{document}
```

You compile it using:

```
make4ht -f odt sample.tex
```

Comment: I just tried ```make4ht -f sample.tex``` and the output was as follows:
```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ? 1457  pdfTeX error : not allowed in DVI mode .
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

Comment: @DudeMcBro this seems like the error you get with the `pdfttex` option

Comment: Its ```pdftex``` via ```pdflatex```. Is there an alternative way to go about it?

Comment: @DudeMcBro you don't need to specify anything for `\usepackage{graphicx}`, LaTeX chooses automatically best option depending on command you use for compilation of your file.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even notice I had put in the ```pdftex``` for ```\usepackage{graphicx}```. I may have put it in at some point while doing some troubleshooting. I honestly don't remember when or why.

Comment: Now, when I run Now, when I do ```make4ht -f odt sample.tex``` I get the following:
``` htlatex: ./0.main.tex  76  Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./0.main.tex  76  Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete.```

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3737; columnNumber: 46; The element type "text:p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</text:p>".
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
 at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
 at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:1300)
 at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:783)
 at xtpipes.Xtpipes.mainMethod(Xtpipes.java:665)

Comment: --- xtpipes error 29 --- At <sax content-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManager,tex4ht.OoFilter" lexical-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManagerLH" > : While parsing file file:/home/dudemcbro/SpiderOak%20Hive/Documents/College/1.%20University%20of%20Maine/1.thesis/mastersthesis/thesis/0.main.tmp: : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3737; columnNumber: 46; The element type "text:p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</text:p>".

Comment: [WARNING] xtpipes: Tidy failed as well
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of 0.main.4oo failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/text:section) [char=214790]

[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished

Comment: The .odt file it creates is corrupted and can't be opened.

Comment: @DudeMcBro It seems like a issue in some of the inputed files, but I cannot test it, as I don't have access to them. Try to comment out all `\include` commands, test if it still fails, and if it doesn't enable the included files again one by one, so you can find where the issue happens.

Comment: I can get the conversion to work fine as long as I don't include any sections that utilize pgfplots, it seems. Hrm.....

Comment: @DudeMcBro ah I see. There is still no support for SVG graphicx in the `make4ht` ODT output. I can try to work on it, could you post a new question just with a `pgfplots` example, as it is quite different from the original issue?